# передача данных через JSON

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, flask

```
<div class="crug" onclick="sending(1891)"></div>
```

у меня есть html объект при нажатии на который вызывается функция:

```
function sending(date) {
            fetch('/', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(date)
            })
        }
```

и обработчик на flask который принимает JSON и должен открывать другой html Документ:

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def ind():
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == "POST":
        date = request.get_json()
        print(date)
        return render_template('ok.html')
    return render_template('index.html')
```

но почему то новый документ у меня не открывается. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Что значит «не открывается»? А вы результат fetch никак не используете, что по вашему должно произойти?

Comment: И вообще, почему это не простая форма без всяких джейсонов и скриптов?

Comment: я хочу чтобы открывался ok.html

Comment: хотелось бы конечно сделать это через JSON

Comment: Ну продолжайте грызть кактус. И ещё раз: вы вызываете fetch, но ничего не делаете с ответом. Почему вы ожидаете что откроется новый документ?

Comment: хорошо, попробую сделать через отправку формы и уберу fetch, спасибо за подсказку!